# How is sentiment score calculated in the R SentimentAnalysis package?

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis, sentimentr

I'm using the General Inquirer dictionary with the SentimentAnalysis package and I can't figure out how they assign the sentiment score...

For example, if I run the following code:

```
sentiment <- analyzeSentiment(sampledf)

summary(sentiment$SentimentGI)
```

I'll get an output like this:

```
Min.      1st Qu.   Median     Mean      3rd Qu.     Max. 

-0.80000  -0.16667  -0.07692   -0.07313  0.00000     0.66667
```

What's the scale being used here? -1 to 1? I don't know how to interpret these results.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend reading the package's [introduction vignette](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SentimentAnalysis/versions/1.3-2/vignettes/SentimentAnalysis.Rmd) which includes references where the implemented methods are described.

Answer (score 2):

All **sentiment**-related scores are calculated based on the formula

```
(#positive - #negative) / #all
```

where `#positive` refers to the number of positive words, `#negative` to the number of negative words and `#all` to the total word count. Hence, the sentiment score comes from the interval [-1, +1]. A value of `0` indicates that there are as many positive as negative words in a document.

NB: In practice, the empirical mean/median value is not necessarily located at exactly zero as either positive/negative is perceived stronger or even appears more frequent. Hence, one would prefer to choose a different cutoff point to discriminate positive from negative.

Other scores are as follows:

- **Negativity** or positivity only count the ratio of negative or positive words, respectively. Hence, this value is given by e.g. `#negative / #all` and is in [0, 1].
- **Polarity** uses the formula `(#positive - #negative) / (#positive + #negative)`.
- **Ratio** is the share of dictionary expressions, i.e. `(#positive + #negative) / #all`.